# How to resolve "Cannot redeclare config() error"?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare config() (previously declared in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-trial\cake\basics.php:59) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp-trial\cake\basics.php on line 76

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: What version of Cake is that, and have you edited the `basics.php` file in any way?

Comment: You might consider updating your question title to be more specific. Like "CakePHP Error: Cannot redeclare config()".

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have created a global function called `config` somewhere. `config` is already declared in global space by cakephp in the file `basics.php`.

Either rename *your* function or move it into a class.

Answer (score 0):

You create two config() function in basic.php. could you post you basic.php code so i will give you right ans.